# Hausdorff dimension of Sierpinski triangle

Tags: metric-spaces, fractals

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension#Behaviour_under_unions_and_products Wikipedia page says that 
if $ \underset{i \in I}{\cup} X_i = X$ and $I$ is countable then
$dim_{Haus}(X) = \underset {i \in I}{sup}\{ dim_{Haus}(X_i)\}$

But isn't Sierpinski triangle union of countably many one dimensional triangles?
What am I missing?

Comment: There are many points in the Sierpinski triangle that are not on the edges of the open triangles of its complement. A similar case is the Cantor set: There are many points in the Cantor set that are not end-points of the open intervals of its complement.

Comment: It seems like I confused Sierpinski triangle with one other construction that I assumed when I saw the picture. So if triangle is constructed by removing the open triangles from the starting one it's not the same as drawing triangles one by one?

Comment: No it isn't the same result. There are limit points of the edges. The union of the set of edges is not a closed set. But it might seem that it is.

Comment: Let the vertices of the beginning triangle be the vectors $A,B,C$. Any point in triangle $ABC$ equals$ a A+b B+c C$ for unique $a,b,c\in [0,1]$ with $a+b+c=1.$ If $p=a A+b B+c C$ is on an edge, at least one of $a,b,c$ is $p/2^q$ for some natural numbers $ p,q.$ But  $p=a A+b B+c C$ belongs to the Sierpinski set when, in the binary representation of $a,b,c,$ the  $n$th digits $a_n,b_n,c_n$ add to $1$, for  every $n.$ This includes points where $a,b,c$ are all irrational